# ORACLE Query to check if one field has changed to another specific

Tags: oracle

We recently noticed that some workes have the maximum rate (13) when they barely have any bought items, so we need a query that checks if any worker rate changes to the maximum so we can check if its legit.

So I have these two tables:

Table1-> **Workers** (DNI,RATE,TICKET,PRICE,...)

Table2-> **Sells** (DNI,NAME,DATE)

**edit**: DATE and RATE are both Strings, Date follows this structure: YYYYMMDD

Sells table have a special discount depending on the rate of the client.

I want to check if any of those wokers rate changes from something that is **not 13** -->  **to 13**

The only way this can happen if is the worker buys a lot, or if someone  changes it manually so they get a better discount (**NOT ALLOWED**).

So, I want to check if yesterday any worker had a 6 rate and today its 13.

```
SELECT RATE,DNI FROM SELLS WHERE RATE='13' AND DNI IN 
(
SELECT DNI FROM WORKERS
)
AND DATE = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Is there any way to UNION those so the matched remain?

```
SELECT RATE,DNI FROM SELLS WHERE RATE <> '13' AND DNI IN 
(
SELECT DNI FROM WORKERS
)
AND DATE to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')
```

Or is there any better way?

Edit of what tried:

Real query:

```
select
  coalesce(t.dni, y.dni) as dni,
  t.Tarifa as today_rate,
  y.Tarifa as yesterday_rate
from (
  SELECT Tarifa, DNI FROM pws_ventas_materiales,pws_ventas_cabecera
  WHERE Tarifa='13' 
    AND DNI IN (SELECT DNI FROM trabajadores_sirgo)
    AND pws_ventas_materiales.fecha = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd')
    and pws_ventas_materiales.ticket = pws_ventas_cabecera.ticket
    and pws_ventas_cabecera.fecha = pws_ventas_materiales.fecha
) y
full join (
  SELECT Tarifa, DNI FROM pws_ventas_materiales ,pws_ventas_cabecera
  WHERE Tarifa <> '13' and Tarifa is not null
    AND DNI IN (SELECT DNI FROM trabajadores_sirgo)
    AND pws_ventas_materiales.fecha = to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')
    and pws_ventas_materiales.ticket = pws_ventas_cabecera.ticket
    and pws_ventas_cabecera.fecha = pws_ventas_materiales.fecha
) t on t.dni = y.dni
;
```

Table Updates:

pws_ventas_materiales=**Sells**

trabajadores_sirgo=**Workers**

**pws_ventas_cabecera** --> There was a mistake on the Sells table, that table does not contain a DNI column, this table does.

Sorry for that mistake

Also, rate=Tarifa and date=fecha + I added a `pws_ventas_materiales.ticket = pws_ventas_cabecera.ticket` to make sure that we are talking about the same sell between those two tables.
[image]

Comment: You treat the column `date` like a string column comparing it with `to_char(...)`. Is this a mistake? Is `date` not a date column, but a string column? And is `rate` a string column or why do you have `WHERE RATE='13'` and not `WHERE RATE=13`? And you select from the `sells` table and one of the conditions in its `WHERE` clause is `AND DATE = ...`, but there is no `date` column in the `sells` table. Or you forgot to tell us so.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It was both a forgot to tell and a mistake, yes, the column Date is a string, and yes, the Rate column is a string too. But in the case of the Date in column sells that was a mistake, The workers table has no Date but the Sell does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join both queries to compare. In this case I would think that an full outer join is more appropriate. For example:

```
select
  coalesce(t.dni, y.dni) as dni,
  t.rate as today_rate,
  y.rate as yesterday_rate
from (
  SELECT RATE, DNI FROM SELLS 
  WHERE RATE='13' 
    AND DNI IN (SELECT DNI FROM WORKERS)
    AND DATE = to_char(sysdate-1, 'yyyymmdd')
) y
full join (
  SELECT RATE, DNI FROM SELLS 
  WHERE RATE <> '13' 
    AND DNI IN (SELECT DNI FROM WORKERS)
    AND DATE to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd')
) t on t.dni = y.dni
-- WHERE today_rate is not null -- extra filtering here
```

Also, the following query can compare all dates, not just today and yesterday:

```
select *
from (
  select
    dni, date, rate,
    lag(date) over(partition by dni order by date) as prev_date,
    lag(rate) over(partition by dni order by date) as prev_rate
  from workers
) x
where prev_rate <> '13' and rate = '13'
```

Comment: A full outer join is easier with `USING` intead of `ON`, so you don't need `COALESCE` on the joined on column(s).

Comment: It does work but in the case of Rate being null it also shows it, I tried to change the " WHERE RATE <> '13'  or rate is not null " but its not working

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I don't use `USING` at all and I never realized it produces less columns than `ON` (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7e128b06bd28c79c55fb669dcdc6e14a). Thank you for this.

Comment: @Erik The predicate `rate = '13'` should remove nulls altogether. Can you provide a small fiddle with an example of the case it's not working as expected?

Comment: @TheImpaler Big Edit, sorry for the error on the first question :(

Comment: @Erik You can add an extra filtering at the end. I edited the first query and added a commented line that you can uncomment to remove rows you don't want.